# Query to check indexing and its types

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms, sql-server-2005

Is there any query through which we can get the list of tables in a selected database with the information that whether indexing is done in that or not and if done then of which type: 
Clustered
NonClustered

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
SELECT   
    i.name as IndexName,  
    o.name as TableName,  
    i.type_desc
FROM    sys.indexes i
join sys.objects o on i.object_id = o.object_id 
where i.[type] = 2  
and i.is_unique = 0  
and i.is_primary_key = 0 
and o.[type] = 'U'
```

Comment: I would join to `sys.tables` instead of having to define the type of your `sys.objects`.......

Answer (score 0):

The query below will only list User tables and also list tables without indexes. Tables without indexes will have a `NULL` in the `index_name` column.

```
SELECT   
    sys.objects.name table_name,   
    sys.indexes.name index_name, 
    sys.indexes.type_desc index_type
FROM sys.objects LEFT JOIN 
     sys.indexes  
ON sys.objects.object_id = sys.indexes.object_id 
where sys.objects.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
```

Comment: I would join to `sys.tables` instead of having to define the type of your `sys.objects` ...

Answer (score 0):

In C# can use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
Server server = new Server(@".\SQLEXPRESS");
Database db = server.Databases["DBName"];
foreach(Table table in db.Tables)
{
     foreach (Index index in table.Indexes)
     {
     }
}
```